# find a $3\times 3$ matrix whose nullspace is the x-axis and whose column space is the yz-plane.

Tags: linear-algebra

Find a $3\times3$ matrix whose nullspace is the x-axis and whose column space is the yz-plane.
I have tried to find that matrix. I found the matrix is

[image]

Is it true ?

Comment: yes seems correct

Comment: @kevinbrown Why don't you prove it for yourself?

Comment: The answer that you've given is indeed one of many correct answers.  Is there some reason you think it might not be?